# How to terminate a regular expression and start another

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have a file which have the data something like this

```
34sdf, 434ssdf, 43fef,
34sdf, 434ssdf, 43fef, sdfsfs,
```

I have to identify the `sdfsfs,` and replace it and/or print the line.

```
The exact condition is the tokens are comma separated. target expression starts with a non numeric character, and till a comma is met.
```

Now i start with `[^0-9]` for starting with a non numeric character, but the next character is really unknown to me, it can be a number, a special char, an alphabet or even a space. So I wanted a `(anything)*`. But the previous `[]` comes into play and spoils it. `[^0-9]*` or `[^0-9].*,` or `[^0-9]\+.*,` or `[^0-9]{1}*,` or `[^0-9][^,]*` or `[^0-9]{1}[^\,]*,` nothing worked till now. So my question is how to write a regex for this (starting character a non numeric, then any character except a comma or any number of character till comma) I am using `grep` and `sed` (gnu). Another question is for posix or non-posix, any difference comes there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that maybe?

```
(?:(?:^(\D.*?))|(?:,\s(\D.*?))),
```

This captures the string that starts with a non-numeric character. Tested [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/wX0oQ6).

I'm not sure if sed supports `\D`, but you can easily replace it with `[^0-9]` if not, which you already know.

EDIT: Can be trimmed to:

```
(?:\s|^)(\D.*?),
```

Comment: yes, this is the correct/working  solution, `sed -r 's/( |^)([^0-9].*?),//g'` and `grep -E "( |^)([^0-9].*?),"` both are working fine. And a trillion thanks for the link, it will help me in future

Answer (score 0):

With sed, and slight modifications to your last regex:

```
sed -n 's/.*,[ ]*\([^ 0-9][^\,]*\),/\1/p' input
```

Comment: this is becoming specific to the sample, suppose sdfsfs is at the beginning of the line, there is no comma or space before that, then `.*,[ ]*` this does not get satisfied, and i'm missing a detection

Answer (score 0):

I think pattern `(\s|^)(\D[^,]+),` will catch it.

It matches white-space or start of string and group of a non-digit followed by anything but comma, which is followed by comma.

You can use `[^0-9]` if `\D` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\b[^0-9,][^,]*/!d' file # only print lines that match
```

or:

```
sed -n 's/\b[^0-9,][^,]*/XXX/gp' file # substitute `XXX` for match
```